# Optimizing the hiding and showing of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this code is already small, but I need help optimizing it as I feel I don't jquery enough to make this code more efficient. So the idea is when you hover over #desno, #loginbox pops out and when you hover over it, it continues to be shown. It gets hidden when your mouse leaves both #desno and #loginbox

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#desno").mouseover(function () {
                $("#loginbox").fadeIn("fast");
            });
            $("#desno").mouseout(function () {
                $("#loginbox").hide();
            });
            $("#loginbox").mouseover(function () {
                $("#loginbox").show();
            });
            $("#loginbox").mouseout(function () {
                $("#loginbox").hide();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Yeah, any help would be appreciated. I would also love it if you'd explain what and how you did it and what was the thought process behind it.

Comment: Actually, this code is better than using toggle() functions. Sometimes toggle may get trigger incorrectly, an you will have the oppsoite effect when entering with mouse cursor. Keep it as it is and use mouseenter

Comment: @GytisŠk Perhaps jQuery's `hover` function may be useful, but I like my CSS answer =3

Comment: `$("#desno,#loginbox").mouseout(...`

Comment: How about minifying the code? That will have an effect. Also, using `on()` is supposed to be quicker than using the aliased versions like `mouseover()`

Comment: @charlietfl I'll try that out. I didn't know you can do that. Cheers

Comment: @MatthewDaly what about mouseout()? Logically would be off, I'll try that

Comment: @HVSHBROWN `mouseover()` is just an alias for `on('mouseover')` and the same is true for all the event handlers like `mouseout()` and `click()`.

Comment: @HVSHBROWN I think you misunderstood. `on()` is for any event, and the first argument is the event name.`mouseout()` is an alias for `on('mouseout`)`

Comment: I understood, took me a while for me to understand that. Thanks to you guys, I formatted the code differently and I wrote a 2 function solution to this, sacrificing the little fadein I had :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#desno,#loginbox").mouseover(function () {
            $("#loginbox").show();
        });
        $("#desno,#loginbox").mouseout(function () {
            $("#loginbox").hide();
        });
    });
```

I asnwered my own question thanks to you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your editor's font to a smaller size.

---

I'm going to assume that `#loginbox` is a child of `#desno` and give you this:

```css
#loginbox {display:none}
#desno:hover #loginbox {display:block}
```

```html
<div id="desno">
  I am desno
  <div id="loginbox">I am loginbox</div>
</div>
```

Good luck getting anything smaller than that.

Comment: I'm trying to use jquery :D altho css would be a valid option, but I can already pull it off as css. Trying to learn jquery and use it in this project I'm working on. Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @HVSHBROWN I would argue that if you can do it in CSS, then you shouldn't do it in jQuery. jQuery is significantly slower.